# Determine position in front of 3D plane (cartesian math)

Tags: math, 3d

I have a planar element in 3D space that I've rotated on the x, y and z axis. I'm positioning a 3D camera in front of the planar but I need to find a way to calculate the x, y, z of the camera.

I'm trying to figure out how to place the camera at x distance from the planes face. There's obviously a bit of trig involved but for the life of me can't figure it out. Gah.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

The relation between distance of a point to a plane is

distance = (Aa + Bb + Cc + D) / sqrt(A^2+B^2+C^2)

for distance to plane Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 from point (a,b,c)

Might need to multiply by -1 to get distance positive.

The equations for the line through point (a,b,c) perpendicular to the same plane is

x = a + At; y = b + Bt; z = c + Ct

So if you have a point in the plane, you can find the equation of the line perpendicular to that plane.  Then you can use the distance constraint to solve for two points a distance along that line - one above the plane, and one below.

Comment: Sorry, that's confused me dramatically. Excuse my ill-math skills but if you could simplify/clarify for me it would be helpful.

Lets say the planar is at A (493, 543, 234) - these x, y, z values are referencing from the centre of the plane - and I want the camera positions at 500 units from that point. The planars rotation is x = 34, y = 54, z = 32.

So I'd like to find out what point B (?, ?, ?) - the camera - is according to the planars rotation. My best guess was to triangulate a point from the planes four vertices (which I for this case will specify as being 400 width).

Comment: I don't understand.  What is A?  What is "the planar?"  Are x, y, and z in degrees?  What is the sense of the rotation?  It sounds like you have a finite sheet, not a plane (which is infinite).  Is this true?

Comment: Lets just follow this equation because it's making more sense than what I wrote in the above comment. If you can help me solve this John I'll award you the answer :-) Lets say my normal vector is N = (400, 500, 600) and my P = (405, 505, 605) I would then calculate my P' by doing this: Camera coords: x = Px + x * Nx y = Py + x * Ny z = Pz + x * Nz I'm I getting this right now? lol...or completely off?

Comment: OK, we have progress. :)  The point in the plane is P = (Px,Py,Pz).  Your normal vector needs to have magnitude 1, so divide each component of N by sqrt(400^2 + 500^2 + 600^2) which is about 877, so N = (Nx,Ny,Nz) is about (400/877, 500/877, 600/877).  You said you wanted a distance 500 from this point.  So then with P' = (Px',Py',Pz'), we have Px' = Px + 500*Nx, Py' = Py + 500*Ny, Pz' = Pz + 500*Nz.  Make more sense?

Comment: Great, haha. Progress is always good.

So I only need to add the magnitude to the normal vector not the secondary P value? I've coded it up and am getting very weird results. Either I need to debug it more closely or I'm getting the calculating wrong. I'll get back to you in the next 30 minutes.

Thank you for your continued patience!

Comment: No - you're starting at P (a vector), and displacing 500 units in the direction of N (adding another vector) to arrive at P'.  You add 500*N to P to arrive at P'.  (I really wish I could boldface letters in comments.  Would make this much easier.)  If you're getting weird results, are you calculating N correctly?  This is where understanding the math might come in.  You need the x, y, and z components of the normal vector.  These might just be the directon cosines, which relate to your angles (34,54,32) (if that's what those numbers are.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try on the weekend, I'm completely swamped with work. I see what you're saying now...ahhhhh.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a plane then you also have its normal vector N and some point on it P.
If you calculate `P'=P+x*N` you'll get the point `P'` which is x units infront of point P in the direction of the normal.

Comment: Hmmmmm. Ok, interesting. Not understanding it 100%, refer to my comment for John W. for a better explanation of what I mean. I'm pretty sure in order to solve this the equation would need to factor in the rotation of the plane to make sure it's facing it correctly.

Comment: David, yes.  Shoosh's answer is a vector equation.  P', P, and N are vectors.  x is a scalar.  The unit vector's components are a direct result of the orientation of the plane.

Comment: Ok, but being the non-math-focused I am I need to understand how to code these values. The Wolfram article is very helpful in explaining the process, but the math is beyond me.

So how could I produce an x, y, z to position the camera from that equation? My guess would be that I have to simply replace N with the vector value.

Comment: "being the non-math-focused" is not an excuse for lazyness. get some decent vector arithmetic book and figure out just exactly it is you want to do.